# SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming to write some transformed dataframes using function:

```
def parquetStreamWriter(dataPath: String, checkpointPath: String)(df: DataFrame): Unit = {
 df.writeStream
   .trigger(Trigger.Once)
   .format("parquet")
   .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointPath)
   .start(dataPath)
}
```

When I am calling this function less number of time in code (1 or 2 dataframes written) it works fine but when I am calling it for more number of times (like writing 15 to 20 dataframes in a loop, I am getting following exception and some of the jobs are failing in databricks:-

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 
time. You can disable broadcast join by setting 
spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.exchange.BroadcastExchangeExec.doExecuteBroadcast(BroadcastExchangeExec.scala:191)
```

My transformation has one broadcast join but i tried removing broadcast in join in code but got same error.

I tried setting spark conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1. as mentioned in error but got same exception again.

Can you suggest where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to judge w/o seeing the execution plan (esp. not sure about broadcasted volume), but increasing the `spark.sql.broadcastTimeout` could help (please find full configuration description [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html)).

Answer (score -4):

1. this can be solved by setting **spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold** to a higher value
2. if one has no idea about the execution time for that particular dataframe u can directly set spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to -1 i.e. (**spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold -1**) this will disable the time limit bound over the execution of the dataframe

Comment: This is not what autoBroadcastJoinThreshold does. From the spark documentation: "Configures the maximum size in bytes for a table that will be broadcast to all worker nodes when performing a join. By setting this value to -1 broadcasting can be disabled. "